# Neo4j - how to include start node in my query?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm attempting to build a recommendation engine for a library system.

This is my db schema:

[image: db schema]

My starting point is a LoanerCard. The flow is then supposed to look like this: Get all copies -> get the material -> get all copies of the material (including the original) -> get LoanerCard from copy -> get all loaned copies -> return the material name of the copies + an aggregated count to indicate the strength of the recommendation.

My best attempt so far has resulted in this query:

```
MATCH (L:LoanerCard {Barcode:"10007"})-[:LOANED]->(myLoans)-[:COPY_OF]- 
(masterMaterial),
(masterMaterial)<-[:COPY_OF]-(allCopies),
(allCopies)<-[:LOANED]-(coLoaners),
(coLoaners)-[r:LOANED]->(theirCopies),
(theirCopies)-[:COPY_OF]-(materials)
RETURN materials.Title as Recommended, count(*) as Strength ORDER BY Strength DESC
```

My issue here is that when I traverse the graph it **doesn't** include the original copy and the adjacent LoanerCards of that so essentially it only traverses the area circled in red and never reaches LoanerCard 10817 and 10558

How can I design my query so it includes these?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `MATCH` clause automatically filters out duplicate relationships. Therefore, in order to traverse the same relationships twice, you need to split your `MATCH` clause in two.

Try this:

```
MATCH (:LoanerCard {Barcode:"10007"})-[:LOANED]->()-[:COPY_OF]-(masterMaterial)
MATCH (masterMaterial)<-[:COPY_OF]-()<-[:LOANED]-()-[:LOANED]->()-[:COPY_OF]-(materials)
RETURN materials.Title as Recommended, count(*) as Strength ORDER BY Strength DESC
```

Comment: thanks it works as intended! Could I have achieved the same by definining the "start" node?

Comment: The `START` clause is deprecated, and would not help you in this case anyway.